# Model value not accessable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model which holds some details about an account (Name, Id etc) and then it has a type called Transaction, which holds information about the currently selected account transaction. A transaction can then have many transaction lines. So I have a `List<TransactionsLine>` property.

I am trying to set the value of a Drop down list, using the model, the value being in the List<> property. At the moment, there can, and must, only be one item in the list.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CategoryId, Model.TransactionReferences.Categories, new {@onchange="populateSubCategory()"})
```

However, when I run this, the list defaults to the first item in the list.

In debug mode, when I hover the mouse over `x.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CategoryId`, it doesn't show me a value. But when hover over the collection, `Model.TransactionReferences.Categories`, I see it has a valid list. It just won't set the selected value.

Am I doing this wrong?

It works in other drop downs I use, BUT the select value is in the top most level of my model:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.ThirdPartyId, Model.TransactionReferences.ThirdParties, new { @class = "cmbThirdParty form-control", @onchange = "populateDefaults()" })
```

That one works fine.

Note, doing it manually, works:

```
<select class="form-control" id="cmbCategory" onchange="populateSubCategory()">
                        <option value="0">Select a One</option>
                        @foreach (var cat in Model.TransactionReferences.Categories)
                        {
                            //var selected = cat.Value == Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[0].CategoryId.ToString() ? "selected" : "";
                            <option value="@cat.Value">@cat.Text</option>   
                        }
                    </select>
```

But doesn't feel like the best way to do it.

Model:

The main model passed to the view:

```
public class TransactionModel
    {
        public int BankAccountId { get; set; }
        public string BankAccountName { get; set; }

        public TransactionContainer Transaction { get; set; }
        public TransactionReferenceModel TransactionReferences { get; set; }

        public DateTime DefaultDate { get; set; }

    }
```

The TransactionReferenceModel holds all my 'reference' data used to populate drop down lists:

```
public class TransactionReferenceModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> TransactionTypes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> EntryTypes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ThirdParties { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CostCentres { get; set; }
}
```

The TransactionContainer model holds allthe main details about the selected transaction:

```
public class TransactionContainer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }

        public int TransactionTypeId { get; set; }
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }

        public int EntryTypeId { get; set; }
        public string EntryType { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

        public string ThirdParty { get; set; }
        public int ThirdPartyId { get; set; }

        public string Account { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "C2")]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public string CategoryDisplay { get; set; }
        public string CostCentreDisplay { get; set; }

        public decimal RunningBalance { get; set; }

        public List<TransactionLine> TransactionLines { get; set; }

    }
```

That then holds a list of transaction lines that make up the transaction. The transaction line holds the property I am trying to set the drop down to, which is CategoryId:

```
public class TransactionLine
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    public int? CostCentreId { get; set; }
    public string CostCentre { get; set; }

    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "C2")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

}
```

And here is how I am populating my model and sending it to the view:

```
public ActionResult EditTransaction(int? transactionId, int? bankAccountId)
        {

            // Create the main view object
            var model = new TransactionModel
                {
                    Transaction = new TransactionContainer
                        {
                            TransactionLines = new List<TransactionLine>()
                        }
                };



            if (transactionId != null) // This is an Edit, as opposed to an Add
            {
                var item = new TransactionService(currentUserId).GetTransaction(transactionId.Value);

                // Populate the Reference object used to populate drop downs.
                model.TransactionReferences = PopulateReferenceDate(model.TransactionReferences, item.TransactionLines[0].SubCategoryId);

                model.BankAccountId = item.AccountId;
                model.BankAccountName = item.Account.FullName;
                model.DefaultDate = Session["DefaultDate"] != null
                                      ? DateTime.Parse(Session["DefaultDate"].ToString())
                                      : DateTime.UtcNow;

                model.Transaction.AccountId = item.AccountId;
                model.Transaction.Amount = item.Amount;
                model.Transaction.TransactionLines.Add(new TransactionLine
                    {
                        Id = item.TransactionLines[0].Id,
                        CategoryId = item.TransactionLines[0].SubCategory.CategoryId,
                        CostCentreId = item.TransactionLines[0].CostCentreId,
                        Notes = item.TransactionLines[0].Notes,
                        Amount = item.TransactionLines[0].Amount,
                        SubCategoryId = item.TransactionLines[0].SubCategoryId,
                        TransactionId = model.Transaction.Id

                    });
                model.Transaction.EntryTypeId = item.EntryTypeId;
                model.Transaction.Id = transactionId.Value;
                model.Transaction.Notes = item.Notes;
                model.Transaction.ThirdPartyId = item.ThirdPartyId;
                model.Transaction.TransactionDate = item.TransactionDate;
                model.Transaction.TransactionTypeId = item.TransactionTypeId;
            }
            else
            {
                // Populate the bank account details
                var bank = new BankAccountService(currentUserId).GetBankAccountById(bankAccountId.Value);
                model.TransactionReferences = PopulateReferenceDate(model.TransactionReferences, null);

                model.BankAccountId = bank.Id;
                model.BankAccountName = bank.FullName;
                model.Transaction.TransactionLines.Add(new TransactionLine
                    {
                        TransactionId = model.Transaction.Id // Link the transaction line to the transaction.

                    });

                var transactionDate = Session["DefaultDate"] != null
                                          ? DateTime.Parse(Session["DefaultDate"].ToString())
                                          : DateTime.UtcNow;

                // Populate the object to hold the Transaction data, so that we can use it and return it in the view.
                model.Transaction.TransactionDate = transactionDate;

            }


            return View(model);


        }
```

Comment: Can you show the model code?

Comment: Added. Hope it makes sense. I am relatively new to MVC, so may be on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the SelectList Constructor in your view, in order to indicate the default value, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Transaction.TransactionsLines[0].CategoryId, 
    new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.Categories, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionsLines[0].CategoryId)
)
```

You are not restricted to use *List< SelectListItem >* for the collections. You can use a List of a specific class also.

This is the Controller Action Method code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var m = new AccountModel();
        m.Transaction = new Transaction();
        m.Transaction.TransactionsLines = new List<TransactionsLine>();
        m.Transaction.TransactionsLines.Add(new TransactionsLine() { CategoryId = 2 });
        m.TransactionReferences = new TransactionReferences();
        m.TransactionReferences.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {   new SelectListItem() { Text = "Cat1", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Cat2", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Cat3", Value = "3" }
        };
        return View(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: This produces the same issue. The selected value isnt selected.

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't seem to be a problem with the property I am setting it to (CategoryId). I just added a new property to my model, hard coded it to a value I know is in the list - but it still does set the selected item in the drop down list.

Comment: I seem to do what I should be doing. I must be doing something wrong.. a basic understanding maybe. I've added my controller method. It's on Edit where it's not working. Note though, that my other drop downs are OK.

Comment: I deleted my Html.DropDownFor code... and re-wrote it, and now it works. I must have had something fishy going on. I also used your method, as opposed to the way I was doing it originally. Fixed. Thanks.